# How do I replace the image of a specific class name?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a script which will select each of the elements with the class name "mainlogo-img" and replace the image source with the file I've indicated. For some reason, this isn't working. Am I writing this script incorrectl

```
<script type="text/javascript">
pageLoc = location;
if (pageLoc == "http://www.barflypub.com/drinks/") {
    logoBox = document.getElementsByClassName("mainlogo-img")
for (i = 0; i < logoBox.length; i++) {
logoBox[i].src = "http://www.barflypub.com/wp-content/gallery/default/img_0962.jpg";
}
</script>
```

Comment: do you have pageLoc and logoBox declared somewhere else? Because I notice they are lacking "var"s. Could that be why?

Comment: Verify that `pageLoc` does exactly match the string you have in the `if` block with `console.log(pageLoc)`.  Then verify that your browser actually has `getElementsByClassName()`. That isn't supported by all browsers.

Comment: Ah, got it, it was the fact that it wasn't loaded after.

Comment: If JavaScript doesn't work as you expect, be sure and check the JavaScript console for any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a `}` missing in the end.